# Fault impedance type?

Tags: power, impedance, fault, power-grid

Usually fault impedances are resistive type. But is it possible to have a mix of resistive and reactive component in fault impedances? Looking at many simulation tools, they give the possibility to apply a reactive component to the fault impedance, therefore I think the answer is yes, but are there practical fault examples? (I'm really interested in single phase to ground examples) (For sure all the impedances have a small reactance due to non ideal conditions/materials, I don't mean this case, I mean the case in which the reactive component is not negligible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don’t normally apply faults that include capacitive or inductive reactance in short-circuit studies.  But, you can sometimes conveniently include them to “lump in” other elements.

For example, if you want to model a ground fault on load side of phase reactors but the reactors are not in your short circuit model.  So your phase-to-ground fault would include the \$X_L\$ of the phase reactor.

Another example, if you want to model a grounded-wye capacitor bank for nearby ground faults (it is a path for zero sequence current flow) you could simply apply it as a three-phase-to-ground fault with capacitive reactance (negative X)…and then go apply your ground fault.  You would do this if you want to see the zero-sequence current flowing in the bank during the external ground fault.  A common backup protection on grounded-wye capacitor banks is zero-sequence time-overcurrent supervised with bus zero-sequence voltage (to block the time-overcurrent from operating during system ground faults with large \$V_0\$ present).

You could also model an imbalanced capacitor bank with two simultaneous faults.  A phase-phase-ground fault with "normal" cap bank \$-X_C\$ as the fault impedance and zero for the ground fault portion.  Then a phase-ground fault with \$-nX_C\$ where n is some number from 0-1 representing part of that phase of the capacitor bank shorted out (assuming fuseless capacitors which fail shorted).  From this you can see the maximum \$V_0\$ you could expect for this condition and set your supervisor above this (for the backup zero-sequence time-overcurrent I mention in previous paragraph).

Etc. etc.

Comment: First of all, thank tou for your answer! I have 1 doubt regarding your answer: but capacitors banks are disconnected during faults, so why to consider their contribution? (Probably are not disconnected in compensated networks with Petersen coil due to lower current, right?)

Comment: Capacitor banks are not disconnected during faults.  They are frequently online during system faults. They may be ignored for most short-circuit studies when you ignore load-flow, but for cases where you care about the specific behavior of the capacitor bank you can include them.